# Where clause with if statement

Tags: c#, linq

Hi all and thanks in advance, I'm stumped on how to use a where clause with the conditional statement that I need to execute. I have two grids of information, one grid is dependent on the other for determining what shows. In the first grid the Date field can be a date or it can say Never.

The first grid's data is like so:

```
ID       Date     Title
---      -----    ------
12       Never    Home
13       Never    School
14       Never    Work
```

The second grid will only show one row of the three depending on what the value of the Date field is, in this example it should be:

```
ID       Date     Title
---      -----    ------
12       Never    Home
```

This information is pulled into a List that I want to iterate through using LINQ. What I want to achieve is:

```
If(All Date values == 'Never') 
    Then pull the first one (12)
else
    if(Date has value)
         then pull the first that has a date

myList.Where(??what goes here??).Select(t => t).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
var record = myList.All(m => m.Date.Equals("Never")) 
               ? myList.FirstOrDefault() 
               : myList.FirstOrDefault(m => !m.Date.Equals("Never"));
```

For more on `.All()` just look at [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Both this and the answer below I think are the best answers; however, this one was exactly what I needed, thanks all!

Answer (score 8):

```
var record = myList.FirstOrDefault(m => !m.Date.Equals("Never"))
               ?? myList.FirstOrDefault();
```

i.e. first one that doesn't equal never or null, and if null, just the first one (or null).

Comment: Much better, it's just thinking about the requirements backwards for a simpler answer.

Comment: This is better, because it makes the least iterations.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have two rules, you will need an if condition somewhere.

The simplest form that I can think of is something like this:

```
return myList.All(x => x.Date == "Never") ? myList.FirstOrDefault() : myList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Date != "Never");
```